# WHERE clause determined at runtime, can this be done with CASE without dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a single query that runs every day of the week, but need to change the WHERE clause condition on one day of the week. On every day except Monday the clause should be:

```
-- If these were two queries they would look like this.
-- On everyday except Monday
Select * FROM Orders
WHERE Order_Date = DATEADD(dd,-1,GETDATE()) -- yesterday's orders

-- On Monday (where DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) returns 2 - find all records from the previous week
Select * FROM Orders
WHERE Order_Date >= DATEADD (DATEADD(dd,-7, GETDATE()
OR
Order_Date <= DATEADD (DATEADD(dd,-1, GETDATE()
```

```
-- On paper this should work, but doesn't:
Select * From Orders 
WHERE
 CASE 
 WHEN DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) = 2 THEN Order_Date >= (DATEADD(dd,-7,GETDATE())) AND Order_Date <= (DATEADD(dd,-1,GETDATE())
 ELSE Order_Date = DATEADD(dd,-1,GETDATE())
 END;
```

Error message is:

```
Incorrect syntax near '>'.
```

Is what I'm trying to do which is essentially 'get CASE to return the SQL code I need'. Is this even possible without dynamic SQL? This has to work in system that doesn't allow EXEC.

Comment: My advice would be not to try and munge them together, check the date in an `if` and have two separate queries - ideally call a separate procedure for each query which would ensure the query has an optimal and sargable execution plan.

Comment: also your `case expression` is invalid so on paper it doesn't work at all, a case expression returns a single value, your where clause is essentially `where <value>`

Comment: As Stu points out, `case` is an expression i.e. it returns a value, you can't use it to evaluate different conditions.

Comment: Also, all `where` clauses are evaluated at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take control of the `DATEFIRST` setting (and set it back when you're done) so that you can determine a Monday without worrying about regional/language settings interfering. Then you can just use a `CASE` expression in the lower bound of the range, and the day as the end of the range:

```
DECLARE @day date = GETDATE(), 
        @df  int  = @@DATEFIRST;

SET DATEFIRST 7;
DECLARE @dw tinyint = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @day);
SET DATEFIRST @df;

SELECT Order_ID, Order_Date 
  FROM dbo.Orders
  WHERE Order_Date >= DATEADD(DAY, CASE @dw WHEN 2 THEN -7 ELSE -1 END, @day)
    AND Order_Date < @day;
```

Easy to test different days by assigning a different value to `@day`; several examples here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7159fd227c576b2ac9fdd619d507ae79)

Another idea if you don't want to mess with `@@DATEFIRST` but you can rely on a specific language is to just test the `DATENAME` of the date in question, and follow the same `CASE` pattern:

```
DECLARE @day date = GETDATE();

SELECT Order_ID, Order_Date 
  FROM dbo.Orders
  WHERE Order_Date >= DATEADD(DAY, CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @day)
    WHEN 'Monday' THEN -7 ELSE -1 END, @day)
    AND Order_Date < @day;
```

(If you can rely on a single language and it's not English, just change it to your language's equivalent of `Monday`.)

Again, easy to test for multiple days; multiple examples here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=570455681919a93b170e33f1cd72d397)

Lots of date/time advice here, including [why we should always avoid shorthand like `dd` and `dw`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations):

- [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates)

Comment: That Idea is a winner.
Thanks for that, I used the following which should be easily readable for whomever has to take care of this next:

`SELECT * FROM Orders
WHERE
ORDER_DATE >= DATEADD(DAY, CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) 
 WHEN 'Monday' THEN -7 ELSE -1 END, GETDATE()) -- If Monday search back -7 days (one week), otherwise look back one day.
 AND
 ORDER_DATE < GETDATE()`

Answer (score 2):

Extremely easy without using dynamic SQL, just use `AND`/`OR` logic.

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
WHERE (
    -- Not Monday
    DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) <> 2
    -- AND Yesterday
    AND Order_Date = CAST(DATEADD(dd,-1,GETDATE()) AS DATE)
)
OR (
    -- Is Monday
    DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) = 2
    -- AND Last week (note you need AND not OR when combining you week restrictions)
    AND Order_Date >= CAST(DATEADD(dd,-7, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
    AND Order_Date <= CAST(DATEADD(dd,-1, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
)
```

Note you need to `cast` your date conditions to a date, else your end up with a time component which will mess with your comparisons. Thats assuming you only store the date for your `Order_Date` if you also store the time this logic would need to change to handle that.

Comment: Thanks for that, I used the following which should be easily readable for whomever has to take care of this next:

`SELECT * FROM Orders
WHERE
ORDER_DATE >= DATEADD(DAY, CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) 
 WHEN 'Monday' THEN -7 ELSE -1 END, GETDATE()) -- If Monday search back -7 days (one week), otherwise look back one day.
 AND
 ORDER_DATE < GETDATE()`